# Retry instruction in salt after fail

Tags: deployment, setup-deployment, salt-stack

I'm using salt for my deployment issues and have the following question.

Is there any mechanism to retry a command?

For instance I have some thing like this:

```
platform_deps_git:
  git.latest:
    - name: ...
    - rev: master
    - target: ...
    - user: ...
    - identity: ...
```

But sometimes the network may fail. Is there any way to retry `platform_deps_git` instruction?

Answer (score 3):

The next version of Salt (2014.7.0) will have an "onfail" requisite. This will allow you to take another action if something fails.

The docs are here:

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onfail

Answer (score 0):

What I do is grep through salt output whenever I run a highstate and if it sees any failures I rerun the highstate.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [first-class retry mechanism](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#retrying-states) for states that was added in 2017:

```
platform_deps_git:
  git.latest:
    - name: ...
    - rev: master
    - target: ...
    - user: ...
    - identity: ...
    - retry:
        attempts: 5
        until: True
        interval: 60
        splay: 10
```

The retry option supports a few different options for controlling its behavior.